# draggable and resizeable input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my input type text box re-sizeable and also make it draggable here's my code

```
    input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = "dragInputelement";
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
    input.type = 'text';
    input.value = "This is input box";
    input.style.position = 'absolute';
    x1 = input.style.left = (x - 30) + 'px';
    y1 = input.style.top = (y - 30) + 'px';
    input.style.background = "transparent";
    input.style.color = '#EC0909';
    input.style.color = defaultcolor;
    input.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.show();
    $("#dragInputelement").draggable();
    $("#dragInputelement").resizeable();
    hasInput = true;
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please add more details and what you want to gain, also better the develop you idea more accurately.

Comment: Hey I just want to make input text box on canvas and want to save it in images array and also want this box draggable and resizeable

Comment: hmm, with a textarea you can easily have resize property, and for drag-and-drop you can use html5 draggable perhaps https://web.dev/drag-and-drop/